# How do I check if int in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, integer

In the question we're asked to remove all even numbers from an array, hence I tried to create a function:

```
import numpy as np 
A = np.array([2,3,4,5])

def remove_even(A):
    if ((A[0])/2) != int: #check if the first value is an integer when divided by 2
        A = A[0:len(A)+1: 2]
        return A
    else:
        A = A[1:len(A)+1:2]
```

However, regardless of my array starting with either an even number (i.e. 2) or an odd number (i.e. 1) the execution of the code goes only as far as to the `if` statement but not to the`else`.

What am I missing? I would appreciate any feedback!

Comment: Are you sure the numbers are always going to be sorted?

Comment: Is this Python 2 or Python 3? On Python 3, `/` on integers returns a `float`. Also: Have a look at [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#isinstance). You are currently comparing an object with a class.

Comment: or use [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type)

Comment: Please [mark an answer as correct](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it resolved your question. This helps us keep track of which questions are left to be answered.

Answer (score 2):

In numpy you can just use a boolean mask:

```
A[(A % 2).astype(bool)]
```

returns

```
array([3, 5])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the below if you need without numpy solution.

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
a = [i for i in l if not i%2]

##print(a) output
##[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code never reaches the `else` clause because the `if` test is always true.

1. No number is equal to `int` because `int` is a class. `!=` is an equality test not a membership test.
2. `4/2` is not of type `int` because the `/` operator gives a `float` result, so the answer is `2.0`. That means `type(A[0]/2)` will always be a `float` irrespective of the value of `A[0]`. So testing the result of the division for membership of `int`, even if correctly done, won't do what you want.

Do this instead:

```
if not (A[0] % 2):
```

This will be true if `A[0]` is not an even number, whether integer or float.